# Delay 2 methods in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, delay

I have a question about the delay of methods. How to properly delay the function "openFile" relative to "Progress". Every time I run it both windows start with a delay of 2sec, and I need openFile () 2sec Progress().

Both methods in the code are working wrong.

Thank you for your help.

```
def get_function(self):
    self.openFile()
    self.after(2000)
    # time.sleep(2)
    Progress(tk.Tk()).get_run_progress_bar()
```

Comment: `.after(2000)` is the same as `time.sleep(2)`. In that 2 seconds, `tkinter` isn't going to update anything and will not respond to user input. Try using `self.after(2000, lambda: Progress(tk.Tk()).get_run_progress_bar())`, that schedules `Progress(...).get_run_progress_bar()` after 2 seconds, while allowing `tkinter` to update itself in the meantime

Comment: I don't know how much time you have been programming but you are very good :D, thank you once again for your help :D GREAT THX.